# Automatically index configured nginx locations

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I've setup nginx as a reverse proxy for some backend services like this:

```
http {
    server {
        listen 80;

        location /service-1/ {
            proxy_pass          http://127.0.0.1:8081/;
            proxy_http_version  1.1;
            proxy_redirect      off;
            proxy_set_header    Host $host;
            proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
        }


        location /service-2/ {
            proxy_pass          http://127.0.0.1:8082/;
            proxy_http_version  1.1;
            proxy_redirect      off;
            proxy_set_header    Host $host;
            proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
        }
    }
}
```

Each of the backend services has `autoindex on;`, so navigating to each of them (*http://localhost/service-1/*, *http://localhost/service-2/*, ...) gives me a quick overview of their exposed contents.

Is there a way to also generate an autoindex for the reverse proxy itself?

I'd like to navigate to *http://localhost/* to get a listing of configured locations.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to also generate an autoindex for the reverse proxy itself?

[autoindex module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_autoindex_module.html) produces **local** directory listing, not service index, i.e. listing every file, directory, and links (softlink/hardlink) under configured `root` directory.

nginx cannot list remote directory if it has no such permission. Probably use network share to do autoindex there, or use application dashboard such as [Heimdall](https://github.com/linuxserver/Heimdall).

Comment: That's fine. I don't want the reverse proxy to list remote directories. I only want it to list the configured locations.

Comment: Doesn't matter, as your locations config is not a local directory, you still can't `autoindex` them. Probably set a `root` directory and create directories respective to your `location` directives there.

Comment: Makes sense. Do you know of another module, besides autoindex, which would use configured locations as a source for an index?

Comment: nginx can't index that because it could be anything, i.e. remote, regex, or exclusions. What nginx do with that is just parse incoming request and apply exact rules according to its configured location. nginx have no idea if `location ~^/images/` could contain `images/favicon.ico`.

Probably you can use [OpenResty](https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module) or just [split your site-specific configurations from nginx core configuration](http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#include) and parse these site-specific files yourself.

Comment: I think this is still a misunderstanding. I'm not looking for a solution that would create an index entry for `images/favicon.ico`. All I want is a an index entry for `images`. Basically so I can click on it. What happens after that is totally up to the backend service.
I see how this wouldn't be achievable for generic locations (endless number of possibilities that could match the regex). But maybe there's a module that does it for simple, non dynamic locations as given in the example above?